# A function that iterates through every row

Tags: r

I'm writing a function but i'm getting slightly confused with the vector structure of R.

I have a table of data where each person has a product and a product value. I have a table of tiers, where each product has tiers with a lower and upper bound, and then a return value.

I want to do the following:

1. Take the product from `data.person`
2. Look at just that product in `data.tiers`
3. Take the value from `data.person`
4. Compare it to the first tier. Return the value if it is in between
   the bottom and top tier.
5. Do the same again for the next tier.

Here's how far i've gotten:

```
Employee <- c("Bob", "Dave", "Sarah")
Product <- c("A", "B", "A")
Value <- c(10, 20, 50)
data.person <- data.frame(Employee, Product, Value)

Product <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
Lower <- c(0,20,0,10)
Upper <- c(20, 999, 10, 999)
Return <- c(0.05, .1, 0.04, .08)
data.tiers <- data.frame(Product, Lower, Upper, Return)

myFunc <- function(product, value)
{
  tiers.temp <- data.tiers %>% 
    filter(Product == product )

  result <- 0

  for (i in length(tiers.temp)){

    if(value >tiers.temp$Lower[i] & value <= tiers.temp$Tier.Upper[i]){
      result <- tiers.temp$Return[i] }
  }

  result

}
```

My function takes the product vector and value vectors as inputs. I want to go in and filter the `data.tiers` table for the product on the current line in my data set. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this based on the vector nature of R.

I then loop through the applicable tiers and perform my test and return a value which I need to assign to a column in the `data.person` table.

**Expected Results:** My final result is a vector of numbers from the `data.tiers` table. So the first line of the data set would return 0.05 as 10 is between 0 and 20.

It would be good to get some info on best practices in a situation like this.

Comment: what is your expected output/results?

Comment: Quick glance suggests you're just creating a histogram. Use a `histogram` function.

Comment: No a histogram is not the intended result. Added the intended output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `dplyr::rowwise()` and add a new column, `value_is_between` to indicate if `Value` is between `Lower` and `Upper`:

```
left_join(data.person, data.tiers, by = "Product") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(value_is_between = between(Value, Lower, Upper)) %>%
  filter(value_is_between == TRUE)

#   Employee Product Value Lower Upper Return value_is_between
#     (fctr)  (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl)            (lgl)
# 1      Bob       A    10     0    20   0.05             TRUE
# 2     Dave       B    20    10   999   0.08             TRUE
# 3    Sarah       A    50    20   999   0.10             TRUE
```

Comment: What's the significance of using rowwise here? What would R do if it wasn't used?

Comment: And just so i'm clear, you're joining the 2 data sets on product. At this point, Bob would have 2 rows as there are 2 tiers. You are then doing a check to see if the number is in between the 2 bounds to determine which rows are kept. As each row will be in one of the tiers, I would never lose any data. Is this correct?

Comment: What would R do if `rowwise` was not used? I'd suggest trying it out and seeing for yourself ;) In addition, I would suggest walking through (stopping the execution) before each pipe `%>%` to see what each step is doing. Per your, I would never lose any data comment -- not necessarily, consider if `Bob` had two records for `Product A` that were between the lower and upper value. Conversely, what if `Bob`'s value for `Product A` was between multiple records in the `data.tiers` `data.frame`? Nevertheless, in this example, you are correct.

Comment: Ok i finally tried it. If instead of the Between function, I use an ifelse to evaluate greater than or equal to the lower tier, and less than the upper tier (no equal). I no longer need to use rowwise. I'm not really sure why that is. Is it because the between function doesn't take a vector for the upper and lower bounds? Would you mind explaining that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `foverlaps` from `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(data.person)
setDT(data.tiers)
setkey(data.tiers,Product,Lower,Upper)
data.person[,Value2:=Value]
foverlaps(data.person,data.tiers,by.x=c("Product","Value","Value2"),
          by.y=c("Product","Lower","Upper"))[,
                  c("Value2","Lower","Upper"):=NULL][]   
#   Product Return Employee Value
#1:       A   0.05      Bob    10
#2:       B   0.08     Dave    20
#3:       A   0.10    Sarah    50
```